# Batch code to open up .xlsm and save as .htm

Tags: excel, batch-file

I am very new to batch code and was needing to make a batch code that will open up a UL.xlsm and save it as a UL.htm in "C:\Users\White Sign Company\Dropbox\UL\". Really new to this so any direction would be great.

Found it can not be done using batch, but I can use vba inside of excel. Use this code it works great.

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = Yes
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:="C:\Users\White Sign Company\Dropbox\UL\UL\UL.htm", _
    FileFormat:=xlHtml
```

Comment: Once the batch file opens the spreadsheet in Excel, there's no way to tell it to then save the file as an HTM file.  The batch-file language doesn't have those types of capabilities.  However, you could use PowerShell to both open the spreadsheet and save it as an HTM.  PowerShell can interact with Excel's COM object, so you should be able to script just about anything.  (One of many examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908302/how-to-open-saveas-then-close-an-excel-2013-macro-enabled-workbook-from-powe)

Comment: I am afraid I have no knowledge of powershell, and would not know even where to start. Thank you for the help, I will be sure to read up on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record the steps in excel macro recorder. You have to rewrite it a bit because it uses a type of syntax that vbs doesn't.

This applies (I don't have a medium9) xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4 in vba.

```
Selection.AutoFormat Format:=xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4, Number:=True, _
    Font:=True, Alignment:=True, Border:=True, Pattern:=True, Width:=True
```

So first look up constants in vba's object browser. xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4 = 17

Then look the function up in object browser and look at the bottom for the function definition,.

```
Function AutoFormat([Format As XlRangeAutoFormat = xlRangeAutoFormatClassic1], [Number], [Font], [Alignment], [Border], [Pattern], [Width])
```

So the vba becomes in vbs (and vbs works in vba) (and as you can see you can work out the correct way without needing to look the function up usually)

Selection.AutoFormat 17, True, True, True,True, True, True

So your code becomes

```
objXLWs.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select.AutoFormat 17, True, True, True,True, True, True
```

You are using Excel and you can record it in Excel and have Excel write your code.

**Alt + T, M, R**

then Home key then Up Arrow. Stop recording.

Look what Excel wrote

```
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
```

or if you had of recorded Go To dialog

```
Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
```

or if you had of recorded Ctrl + Home

```
Range("A1").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a utility to allow you to convert XLS file to any other allowed format (requires excel to be installed ).  Was origionally for Word, but now has a XLS version.  Still in beta really but might do the trick.

https://github.com/tobya/DocTo/releases