# Extract worksheets from Excel into separate files with PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to split an excel file with multi sheets to multi files, and searched this blog:[Extract worksheets from Excel into separate files with PowerShell](http://bryanoconnell.blogspot.com/2012/09/extract-worksheets-from-excel.html)  . I tried xls file, and it works fine. But when I tried xlsx file, it just output the whole source file, with each sheets as the default sheet when I opened the generated files with Excel Application. I am struggled with the solution but with no luck. My test code is like blow:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application" 
$Excel.Visible = $false #Runs Excel in the background. 
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false #Supress alert messages. 

$filepath ="D:\powershell\test.xlsx"
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.open($filepath)
$WorkbookName = "test.xlsx"
$output_type = "xlsx"

if ($Workbook.Worksheets.Count -gt 0) { 
    write-Output "Now processing: $WorkbookName" 
    $FileFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook 

    $WorkbookName = $filepath -replace ".xlsx", "" 

    foreach($Worksheet in $Workbook.Worksheets) {
        $ExtractedFileName = $WorkbookName + "~~" + $Worksheet.Name + "." + $output_type 
        $Worksheet.SaveAs($ExtractedFileName, $FileFormat) 

        write-Output "Created file: $ExtractedFileName"
    }
} 

$Workbook.Close() 
$Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: I'm not sure `if ($Workbook.Worksheets.Count -gt 0) {` is necessary as a workbook cannot contain zero worksheets.

Comment: @Jeeped  I think you are right. As this article(https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-XLSX-PowerShell-f2f0c035), "a minimal Excel XLSX package file" should include 1 mandatory worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In keeping with standard Excel practise, copying a worksheet to no destination will create a new workbook with that worksheet as the solitary worksheet and that workbook will be the [ActiveWorkbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821871.aspx).

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application" 
$Excel.Visible = $false #Runs Excel in the background. 
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false #Supress alert messages. 

$filepath ="D:\powershell\test.xlsx"
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.open($filepath)
$WorkbookName = "test.xlsx"
$output_type = "xlsx"

if ($Workbook.Worksheets.Count -gt 0) { 
    write-Output "Now processing: $WorkbookName" 
    $FileFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook 

    $WorkbookName = $filepath -replace ".xlsx", "" 

    foreach($Worksheet in $Workbook.Worksheets) {
        $Worksheet.Copy()
        $ExtractedFileName = $WorkbookName + "~~" + $Worksheet.Name + "." + $output_type 
        $Excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($ExtractedFileName, $FileFormat) 
        $Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

        write-Output "Created file: $ExtractedFileName"
    }
} 

$Workbook.Close() 
$Excel.Quit() 
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
Stop-Process -Name EXCEL
Remove-Variable Excel
```

Now that does propagate the workbook into multiple workbooks each with a copy of a single original worksheet. I've piled a couple of 'murder Excel' commands into the tail end of that in order to *not* end up with a rogue (and invisible) excel.exe sitting in the Task Manager's Processes tab.

There is an excellent thread on removing that last instance of excel.exe in [How to Open; SaveAs; then Close an Excel 2013 (macro-enabled) workbook from PowerShell4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908302/how-to-open-saveas-then-close-an-excel-2013-macro-enabled-workbook-from-powe).

Comment: So the `$Worksheet.SaveAs` method in the openXML version is very different from the xls version? I am very new to PowerShell. Thanks for your answer as well as the refer link.

Comment: @WayneCui - I kept at it and managed to get the last instance of excel.exe out of the Processes tab. See above edit. Be aware that it is kind of a blanket command and may interfere with other instances of Excel that you want to keep open.

Comment: Thanks,it's very kind of you to do that and it satisfied my need. Just wandering why the openxml version doesn't support the $Worksheet.SaveAs() method just as the .xls version?